# Selenium webdriver using TestNG - Cannot locate correct Xpath of input field from label

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

here i want to fill the input field, but unable to access it by Xpath... Plz Help me out..

and the Code is below....

```
<table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCol">
                <div id="div1">
                    <div class="pbSubsection">
                        <table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="data2Col" colspan="2">
                                        <span style="font-Size:12px;">
                                            Process Name
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td style="text-align:left;" class="data2Col">
                <div id=div2">
                    <div class="pbSubsection">
                        <table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="data2Col" colspan="2">
                                        <div id="div3" class="requiredInput">
                                            <div id="div4" class="requiredBlock"></div>
                                            <input name="pName" style="width:50%;" type="text">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

iam trying

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Process Name']/preceding::td/div/input[@type='text']"));

ele.sendKeys("PM 001");

But here after preceding i know its wrong.. Plz Help me out with this.......

Here the name attribute value of input and div id's will change dynamically...

so iam trying to find by the label and preceding input tag...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is entirely wrong.

```
//span[normalize-space(text())='Process Name']/ancestor::tr/descendant::input
```

Is what you are after.

If the `name` of that `input` doesn't change, you can simply get it via:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("pName"));
```

Your XPath falls over at the first hurdle simply because that `span` has a **lot** of whitespacing around "Process Name", so use `normalize-space` to force it to strip the whitespaces from the text before comparing it.

You are also then falling over at the next stop, `preceding` ...you are the the `span`'s level here, it's as deep as you can go, there's nothing 'preceding' it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks... Arran.. Your Code its working...

But, here iam using
//span[text()='Process Name']/following::input

even this is working... but just i want to know the difference b/w both...

Answer (score 0):

//span[normalize-space()='Process Name']//ancestor::tr//div//input[@type='text']